# Magento: Track number of downloads of downloadable product links

Tags: magento

I would like to display the number of downloads being done for any downloadable links of a downloadable product in Magento.

I don't think there is such feature in Magento.

Seems we need to program it.

Any help please?

Comment: alternative route would be track it via google analytics ... onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Product Download', 'Download', '<?php echo $_product->getSku()  ?>']);"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the number_of_downloads_bought and number_of_downloads_used in downloadable_link_purchased_item table (Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item model)

Magento uses those fields to define  how many times user can download file:

```
$linkPurchased = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')->load($linkPurchasedItem->getPurchasedId());
$downloadsLeft = $linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsBought()
    - $linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsUsed();
```

So you can use  $linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsUsed() as number of downloads in selected order. If you count number of doewnloads for every order you can get total number of downloads.

Or you can make your own counter for calling Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController::_processDownload()

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Didn't notice that earlier. Seems it might solve my problem. Will get back to you after I do some work as per your suggestion/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the field 'number_of_downloads' in the table 'downloadable_link'?

Comment: That's for number of download allowed for any particular link. Not the total count of how much the link has been downloaded.