# Get access to $item->getNumberOfDownloadsUsed() function on Download.php

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I need to get the number of downloads bought and used, that's two methods that are available on `$item` object. But I can't instance `$item` on the file that I'm working:

`app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/Download.php`

On this file, I need to retrieve the number of boughts and used of the download purchased.

I'm also trying to get the order ID or at least the link hash to identify that number of boughts/used downloads with the unique id of the purchase.

For example, I try this:

```
Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')
            ->load($this->getOrderItem()->getOrder()->getId(), 'order_id');
```

But `$this->getOrderItem()` is not available on `Download.php` file. I was trying this:

```
Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $this->getOrderItem()->getId());
```

But obviously `getOrderItem()` is unavailable.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Downloadable_Helper_Download::getOrderItem() in /[...]/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/Download.php on line 135

But I'm able to use the customer singleton to retrieve client data like this:

```
$cliente = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

So on this file I'm able to access others methods, but I'm unable to get the following details:

- Number of downloads bought
- Number of downloads used
- Order ID or Link hash ID.

So please, I'm requesting how to get the current order instance and / or the current link instance, on the `Download.php` related with the file downloading.

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't this functionality be a part of the model? (and not the helper)

Comment: have you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957878/4349218

Comment: @OfirBaruch maybe could be. But I don't know how to pass that information to the helper, that's where I need to get the data.

Comment: @Piyush yes, but on the file that I write that it doesn't return any value. Objects are null, that's because I can't access that data on helper. Because I haven't got instance of `$linkPurchasedItem`

Comment: You may disagree but I encourage you to look for a different approach as helpers are just groups of functions without relation or data-oriented. Helper for HTML elements, helper for tax calculations, helper for handling images - fine, but the moment you start to integrate it with model-data... its breaks the MVC architecture. (Just my opinion)

Comment: You're right. I need a helper. I tell you the story: my client needs that downloadable products will be redirections to sell a virtual product. Yes, a crap, but it is. I achieve all functionality but maybe some smart clients can buy a link and access it several times because the redirection to an external page, so I need to pass a POST variable to control how many purchases available has that client to block if he/she access to redirection more times than the number of downloads purchased. So the redirection is on that helper, but I can't retrieve number of boughts.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude can you tell on which page you are trying to access this helper?

Comment: @Piyush I tell it on the question: `app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/Download.php`. It's when a customer purchase a downloadable product, go to my account -> my downloadable products and then click on the downloadable link. Instead of download I redirect to a page. That code is on this helper. Maybe I can retrieve the data from another file, but I don't know what and how.

Comment: For example: `https://www.domain.tld/downloadable/download/link/id/MC4yMDQyNzEwMCAxNTEwNzQ0ODQyMTcyODE1/` and this link is clicked on `https://www.domain.tld/downloadable/customer/products/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you can not get any object like this `$this->getOrderItem()` without set/declaring them. As you are trying to get `order_id` and `item_id` in the helper, which you are using on a custom page redirected from customer downloadable products. Here is what you have to do

### **Step - 1**

From customer My Downloadable products, in the redirect url you have to pass that products `order_id` and `item_id` as parameter. You can get them from below code

```
$orderId = $_item->getPurchased()->getOrderId();
$itemId = $_item->getId();
```

### Step -2

Now in your template file while using your helper function pass this `order_id` and `item_id` to method parameter.  Like below code

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_param');
$itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('item_param');

//Your helper function
Mage::helper('your_helper')->yourMethod($orderId, $itemId);
```

### Step - 3

In your helper file you can use below code

```
public function yourMethod($orderId, $itemId)
{
    $linkPurchasedItem = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')
            ->load($orderItem, 'order_id');


    $LinkPurchaseOrderItemId = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $itemId);
}
```

**Note:** Do not make any changes in core files, instead override them